How to upload a big file by RestTemplate?
I get a MultipartFile from users and resent it to an API by RestTemplate. But I get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if a file size biger than 2gb

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: arraycopy: last destination index 2147468288 out of bounds for byte[1819689347]
at java.base/java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.util.FastByteArrayOutputStream.resize(FastByteArrayOutputStream.java:299) ~[spring-core-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
at org.springframework.util.FastByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArrayUnsafe(FastByteArrayOutputStream.java:215) ~[spring-core-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:44) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:889) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:790) ~[spring-web-6.1.8.jar:6.1.8]

Method for sending request:
protected String postFileRestTemplate(String addToBaseURL,
                                          InputStreamResource inputStreamResource) {

       restTemplate.setInterceptors(Collections.singletonList(new LoggingInterceptor()));

        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

        MultipartBodyBuilder builder = new MultipartBodyBuilder();
        builder.part("content", "iso");
        builder.part("filename", inputStreamResource);

        MultiValueMap<String, HttpEntity<?>> build = builder.build();
        HttpEntity<Object> objectHttpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(build, httpHeaders);

        ResponseEntity<String> exchange = restTemplate.postForEntity(
                baseURL + addToBaseURL,
                objectHttpEntity,
                String.class);

        log.info(exchange.getBody());
        return exchange.getBody();

    }

I also write LoggingInterceptor which do nothing, i needed to check the headers, but if i delete this. I get "501 chunked transfer encoding not supported" I don't know why it happend.
  public class LoggingInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {


    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
        ClientHttpResponse response = execution.execute(request, body);
        return response;
    }

I tried to find info on web, but I didn't find any way how to do that.

Any chance the API you are communicating with accepts the file in smaller chunks?
If not can you consider using the raw http client without spring abstractions? Like the Apache HTTP client.

You can use HttpClient:
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingConnectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
    
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setConnectionManager(poolingConnectionManager)
                .build();

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient));


import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

   @Configuration
   public class AppConfig {
         @Bean
        public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
           return new RestTemplate();
  }

}

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
